# How do I wire this motor's terminal plate, and is this motor continuous duty?

Tags: motor

I don't know much about motors, but I have one in mind for my purpose.  You can see an image of it, and I'd like to know how to wire the terminal plate. I plan to use a belt from the motor shaft to turn a shaft on a spherical container for several days.  Can anyone tell me if this is a continuous duty motor?  I'd be grateful for anyone's help.

[image]

Specs:
Synchronous Motor 60KTYZ 110V AC 60Hz 80 RPM CW/CCW 14W Gear Motor

Rated voltage: 110V AC

Rated frequency: 50 ~ 60HZ

Product model: 60KTYZ

Product size: 60mm*60mm

Input power: 14W

Output power: 3.4W

Input current: 63mA

Outlet shaft diameter: 7mm

Shaft length: 18mm

Out shaft position: middle and out shaft

Rotation direction: positive and negative bidirectional (CW/CCW)

Application environment: Temp (-15 -40 OC) Humidity = 90%

Noise: less than or equal to 35dB

Insulation class: E class

Security authentication: CCC, CE, RoHS.

Speed: 80 RPM

Comment: What torque is needed? Direction?  No instructions? Use centre and either outside screw to change direction

Comment: If rust has weakened the steel artwork already, an abrasion drum to clean may weaken it more. Consider other methods to refinish it.https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-rust-remover/

Comment: That motor seems to be very similar to the one in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545999/ac-synchronous-motor-control-circuit The connection is likely the same.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about torque.  Does it relate to the weight of the part being pulled by the drive belt?  The spherical part the belt drive will hopefully rotate weighs about 8 pounds.  I shopped on eBay and asked the seller if he could advise me about wiring, or if the motor came with wiring instructions. but I got no reply.  I also searched online for pre-wired 60 - 80 rpm motors, but the results weren't useful.  I know when dealing with an electrical device there's no room for error.  Error could = fatality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Power is applied to the red and black leads for one direction of rotation and blue and black for the other.

It's a continuous duty motor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I only need the motor to rotate in one direction, so this is good to know.  Thanks for telling me this is a continuous duty motor.  I hope this is an appropriate comment.

Comment: Anytime, DawnaR! I do hope you find that the motor suits your application. All okay.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t say for certain but I’d be highly confident that this is continuously rated.  Firstly, synchronous motors aren’t well suited to stop-start operations, and if it weren’t continuously rated then I would expect the rated on/off times to be published prominently alongside the power/torque.

I can’t say how to wire it, but I’d expect that there are two windings, one direct across live-neutral and one with that red capacitor in series to provide a phase shift.

Answer (score 0):

From the specs it seems a timer motor… in short a motor designed to turn clock gears (for periodic controls and such things). Definitely continuous duty and more importantly precise speed (that's the advantage of small sync motors). In europe the 50Hz version is often 60 RPM on the spindle so they are almost clocks in themselves.

However it's quite a small motor (the gear train usually only has cam switches and such), with only 14W I don't know if it fits your application.

Answer (score 0):

For wiring use the middle and one of the end terminals depending on which direction you want it to spin.

as others have said it's suited for continuous operation